# Tikzpicture / PGF layers rendering in the margin

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic, pgflayers

Alrightly folks, I have one that has stumped me thoroughly and hopefully one of you beautiful brilliant people can help me out.

I am attempting to use tikz/pgf to enable me to use absolute positioning of images and text over my document with coordinates. However, my PGF layers keep rendering inside the margin.

Latex Code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{letter}
\usepackage[lmargin=15pt,rmargin=15pt,tmargin=0pt,bmargin=10pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclarelayer{back}
\pgfdeclarelayer{front}
\pgfsetlayers{back,main,front}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{back}        
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay] {\draw[thick,red,fill] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);}
This is some text, it is on the main layer.\\
    \end{pgfonlayer}    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Any help would sincerely be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `\tikz` inside a `tikzpicture` is not a good idea (`\tikz` is a short form for creating a new `tikzpicture` and they must not be nested). Remove it and directly draw the rectangle (don't forget to compile two times):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{letter}
\usepackage[lmargin=15pt,rmargin=15pt,tmargin=0pt,bmargin=10pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclarelayer{back}
\pgfdeclarelayer{front}
\pgfsetlayers{back,main,front}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{back}        
    \fill[red] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}    
    \node at (current page.center) {text on main layer};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First, thanks for clearing up some of structure. Is it acceptable to nest tikzpictures or is that always a no no?

Comment: Second..... THANK YOU SO MUCH! Some how I had never discovered that I needed to compile twice and this has been haunting me for weeks through all my projects trying to use certain packages. Your extra effort to remind me to compile two times has changed my life for the better. I am in your debt.

Comment: @JamesDunlap First: In general you should not nest tikzpictures. While this might sometimes give the results you want, problems caused by this are a pain in the a** to debug, so better never nest them. And in the code you show nesting them really makes no sense.

Comment: @JamesDunlap Second: My pleasure to help! Compiling two times is necessary because in the first run tikz has to look up all kinds of things, like how big the page is. I the second run it can use all these stored variables to correctly position things.